# Perl - Hash::Merge loses keys

Tags: perl, hashmap

I'm trying to merge two blessed hashes in Perl.

I'm running the following code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Hash::Merge;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $hash1 = bless( {
                 'CalcPorts' => {
                                  'helper_1' => {
                                                  'Scope' => [
                                                               ''
                                                             ],
  
                                                },
                                  'helper_2' => {
                                                  'Scope' => [
                                                               ''
                                                             ],
 
                                                },
                                },
 
               }, 'IB' );
my $hash2 = bless( {
                 'CalcPorts' => {
                                  'helper_2' => {
                                                  'Scope' => [
                                                               'd'
                                                             ],
 
                                                },
                                },
 
               }, 'IB' );

my $merger = Hash::Merge->new('LEFT_PRECEDENT');    
my $hash3 = $merger->merge($hash2, $hash1);

print Dumper($hash3);
```

The output is this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'CalcPorts' => {
                                  'helper_2' => {
                                                  'Scope' => [
                                                               'd'
                                                             ]
                                                }
                                }
               }, 'IB' );
```

Even though I would have expected the "helper_1" to be there...
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It seems it doesn't merge blessed hashes at all, try changing the top key in $hash1 to a different string. If you remove [bless](http://p3rl.org/bless), though, it starts to work.

Comment: But I need it to work with blessing... If I remove the blessing, I need to find a way to return it back when I finish with the merging... and there is blessing all over the values of the hash

Comment: I'd say: For you they are still hashes, but once blessed for Hash::Merge they might be just another unsupported data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hash::Merge` considers that anything whose `ref` isn't `HASH` or `ARRAY` is a scalar, and applies the scalar merging rules on those items (see [those lines](https://metacpan.org/dist/Hash-Merge/source/lib/Hash/Merge.pm#L217-221) of the implementation of `Hash::Merge`). When merging 2 scalars, `Hash::Merge` either discards one of them, or create an array to store them both. None of this options merges blessed hashes.

To overcome this issue, you can unbless your hashes first (using [`Data::Structure::Util::unbless`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Structure::Util#unbless($ref)) for instance), then merge them, then rebless them:

```
use Data::Structure::Util qw(unbless);
my $class = ref $hash1;
unbless $hash1;
unbless $hash2;
my $hash3 = bless $merger->merge($hash2, $hash1), $class;
```

If you have blessed hashes within your main hashes, then you can define your own `Hash::Merge` behavior with the [`add_behavior_spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#add_behavior_spec(-%3Chashref%3E,-%5B%3Cname%3E%5D-)) method: for the `SCALAR`-`SCALAR` case, check if both scalars are blessed references, and, if so, unbless, merge, and rebless:

```
$merger->add_behavior_spec(
    { 'SCALAR' => {
        'SCALAR' => sub {
            my $self  = &Hash::Merge::_get_obj;
            my ($left, $right) = @_;
            my ($class_left, $class_right) = (ref $left, ref $right);
            if ($class_left && $class_left eq $class_right) {
                unbless $left;
                unbless $right;
                return bless $self->merge($left, $right), $class_left;
            } else {
                return $_[1]; # Or something else
            }
        },
        'ARRAY'  => ...,
        'HASH'   => ...,
    },
    ARRAY => { ... },
    HASH  => { ... }
```

For conciseness, I've left `...` for cases that are not relevant. You can copy-paste those from [the source of `Hash::Merger`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Hash-Merge/source/lib/Hash/Merge.pm#L24-95) (choosing the behavior that you want). Or, maybe easier, you can use [`get_behavior_spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#get_behavior_spec(-%5B%3Cname%3E%5D-)) and [`get_behavior`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#get_behavior(-)) methods to change the `SCALAR`-`SCALAR` case of the current behavior:

```
my $behavior = $merger->get_behavior_spec($merger->get_behavior);
my $old_behavior_scalar_scalar = $behavior->{SCALAR}{SCALAR};
$behavior->{SCALAR}{SCALAR} = sub {
    my $self  = &Hash::Merge::_get_obj;
    my ($left, $right) = @_;
    my ($class_left, $class_right) = (ref $left, ref $right);
    if ($class_left && $class_left eq $class_right) {
        unbless $left;
        unbless $right;
        return bless $self->merge($left, $right), $class_left;
    } else {
        # Regular scalars, use old behavior
        return $old_behavior_scalar_scalar->($left, $right);
    }
};
```

Note that this does not handle well cases where you want to merge 2 hashes blessed to 2 different packages. You'll have to implement special cases for those. (it's not clear what a general rule for merging such hashes would be)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting a new error (following your code). I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69114461/perl-deep-recursion-on-subroutine-hashmergemerge). If you could take a look, that would be great. Thanks!