# perl - Hash::Merge duplicates same list within hashes instead of putting them once

Tags: perl, merge

I'm trying to merge two hashes that hold lists inside them.
The thing is that those lists are exactly the same, but because they are lists, the merger duplicates their values inside.

Any ideas how can I remove the duplication?

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Hash::Merge;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $hash1 = {
                 
                 'Instance' => [ 1,2 ]
                 
               };
my $hash2 = {
                 'Instance' => [ 1,2 ] 
    };


my $merger = Hash::Merge->new('LEFT_PRECEDENT');    
my $hash3 = $merger->merge($hash2, $hash1);
print Dumper($hash3);
```

The output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Instance' => [
                          1,
                          2,
                          1,
                          2
                        ]
        };
```

What I want is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Instance' => [
                          1,
                          2
                        ]
        };
```

AFTER EDIT:
I posted a continuing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174664/perl-hashmerge-duplicates-same-list-within-hashes-instead-of-putting-them-on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often when you want to do something a bit advanced with `Hash::Merge`, the answer is "implement your own custom behavior".

In this case, you can do:

```
my $merger = Hash::Merge->new('LEFT_PRECEDENT');
my $behavior = $merger->get_behavior_spec($merger->get_behavior);
$behavior->{ARRAY}{ARRAY} = sub {
    my ($left, $right) = @_;
    my %seen = map { $_ => 1 } @$left;
    return [ @$left, grep { ! $seen{$_} } @$right ];
};

my $hash3 = $merger->merge($hash2, $hash1);
```

Where the line `my %seen = map { $_ => 1 } @$left;` populates the hash `%seen` with the values of the `$left` array, and `grep { ! $seen{$_} } @$right` filters the `$right` array by keeping only the values that are not in `%seen`.

Note that this approach does not remove all duplicates: if `$left` or `$right` contain duplicate elements (eg, if `$left = [1, 1, 2]`), then those duplicates will remain. If you want to remove all duplicates, then use this version instead:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
$behavior->{ARRAY}{ARRAY} = sub {
    my ($left, $right) = @_;
    return [ uniq @$left, @$right ];
};
```

If, for any reason, you don't want to rely on [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) for the `uniq` function, you can easily implement your own: [How do I remove duplicate items from an array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7651/4990392).

Comment: It works great on regular numbers, but for some reason when it's combined with [blessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69114461/perl-deep-recursion-on-subroutine-hashmergemerge) example (which you gave answer to that too), it still duplicates. I understand there's a problem with the blessing, but I would have thought that after unbless works and $self->merge goes again, that it would run your change in this answer here and not duplicate the 'LineNumber' => bless( do{\(my $o = '200773952')}, 'Veri::ColLineFile' )...

Comment: @urie I don't quite understand the issue. Any chance that changing the `LEFT_PRECEDENT` to `RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT` fixes your problem?

Comment: I added a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174664/perl-hashmerge-duplicates-same-list-within-hashes-instead-of-putting-them-on)

Comment: @urie Good call, it's better to add a new question than to substantially edit the old one. I know how to fix your issue; not sure if I'll have time to answer today though.